# Setting default doc type values in umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco7

I have two document types in umbraco called homeFixture & awayFixture and i would like to set the default value of a label (that will never change) when a new page is created. I have the following code which sets the value when i choose to create a new page

```
public class DocTypeCreateEventHandler : ApplicationEventHandler
    {
        protected override void ApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        {
            ContentService.Created += ContentService_Created;
        }

        void ContentService_Created(IContentService sender, Umbraco.Core.Events.NewEventArgs<Umbraco.Core.Models.IContent> e)
        {
            if (e.Entity.ContentType.Alias.ToString() == "homeFixture")
            {
                e.Entity.SetValue("location", "Home");
                e.Entity.SetValue("homeTeam", "Liverpool FC");
            }
            if (e.Entity.ContentType.Alias.ToString() == "awayFixture")
            {
                e.Entity.SetValue("location", "Away");
                e.Entity.SetValue("awayTeam", "Liverpool FC");
            }

        }
    }
```

However, when i select save and publish the default values that i am seeing when i create the page are disappearing. Does anyone know how i can persist these values once saved and published?

I am using umbraco v7.4

Thanks

Comment: I'd think you need to save the entity after you set any values, especially if you use _Created event and not _Creating?

Comment: Hm. Upon further inspection, _Creating is deprecated and it works for me without saving the entity. Are your "location" and "home/awayTeam" properties of type textstring or textarea?

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. take a look at this post https://our.umbraco.org/forum/extending-umbraco-and-using-the-api/78993-set-default-value-of-property-using-events. I solved this by using the saving event as you quite rightly mention creating is now Obsolete.

Comment: Ah, the properties are labels? That might be why _Created doesn't cut it, although I don't see why it shouldn't. Well, as long as you found a solution :-)

Comment: Yes, the properties are labels. Yeah it's sorted for now so happy with the solution and using .saving instead. Thanks for your help